# Fade out exit requires 2 clicks instead of one

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, fadeout

I'm trying to implement a fade in/out to main form open/close, open fade in works fine, however close fade out requires 2 button clicks to work.

Current code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Threading;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

namespace DEMO
{

    public partial class MainForm : Form

// fade in timer set
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer t1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer t2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //fade in function
            Opacity = 0;
            t1.Interval = 10;
            t1.Tick += new EventHandler(fadeIn);
            t1.Start();
        }
        // fade in
        void fadeIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Opacity >= 1)
                t1.Stop();
            else
                Opacity += 0.05;
        }
         // fade out
        void fadeOut(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Opacity <= 0)
            {
                t2.Stop();
                Close();
            }
            else
                Opacity -= 0.15;
        }

        protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnFormClosing(e);
           e.Cancel = true;

            t2.Tick += new EventHandler(fadeOut);
            t2.Start();

            if (Opacity <= 0)
                e.Cancel = false;
        }

        private void customImageButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }

}
```

I first tried to make it like the button to do the tick start with the `e.Cancel` but changing the `EventArgs e` to `FormClosingEventArgs e` only gave the error: `No overload for 'customImageButton1_Click' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'` on which I couldn't find a solution

Comment: You didn't post the `fadeIn` method. Do you remove `fadeIn` from  `t1.Tick` anywhere in your code? Otherwise t1.Tick will call both `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`. Also, in `OnFormClosing` you check `Opacity == 0` whereas in `fadeOut` `Opacity <= 0`.

Comment: so that's why, I've modified the code to reflect the questions, and now it works, I created a new timer t2 and used for the fade out, and now it works. I'll modify the code in here to reflect the new one, thanks